# How to sort strings using two substring equality conditions?

Tags: sorting, perl

I have a list of strings with the following format:

`('group1-1', 'group1-2','group1-9', 'group2-1','group2-2', 'group2-9','group1-10', 'group2-10' )`

I need them to be sorted as below:

group wise first and then number wise.

`('group1-1', 'group1-2','group1-9','group1-10', 'group2-1','group2-2', 'group2-9', 'group2-10' )`

I've written following code, but it's not working as expected:
a comparator that sorts based on the group and if the groups match, it sorts based on the number.

```
my @list = ('group1-1', 'group1-2','group1-9', 
'group2-1','group2-2', 'group2-9','group1-10', 'group2-10' );
@list = sort compare @list;
for (@list){
    print($_."\n");
}

sub compare{
    my $first_group, $first_num = get_details($a);
    my $second_group, $second_num = get_details($b);
    if($first_group < $second_group){
      return -1;
   } elsif($first_group == $second_group){
      if ( $first_num < $second_num) {
         return -1;
      } elsif ( $first_num == $second_num ) {
         return 0;
      } else {
         return 1;
      }
   } else{
      return 1;                       
   }
}

sub get_details($){
   my $str= shift;
   my $group = (split /-/, $str)[0];
   $group =~ s/\D//g;
   my $num = (split /-/, $str)[1];
   $num =~ s/\D//g;
   return $group, $num;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @list = ('group1-1', 'group1-2','group1-9', 
    'group2-1','group2-2', 'group2-9','group1-10', 'group2-10' );

@list = map  { $_->[0] }
        sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }
        map  { [$_, split /-/] }
        @list;

for (@list) {
    print($_."\n");
}
```

Prints:

```
group1-1
group1-2
group1-9
group1-10
group2-1
group2-2
group2-9
group2-10
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a little detail with the data here that can lead to a quiet bug. When you use the pre-hyphen substring for sorting (`group1` etc), it has both letters *and* numbers so when sorted lexicographically it may be wrong for multi-digit numbers.  For example

```
group1, group2, group10
```

is `sort`-ed (by default `cmp`) into

```
group1
group10
group2
```

What is wrong, I presume.

So inside sorting we need to break the `groupN` into `group` and `N`, and sort numerically by `N`.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @list = ('group1-1', 'group1-2','group1-9',
    'group2-1','group2-2', 'group2-9',
    'group1-10', 'group2-10',
    'group10-2', 'group10-1'                    # Added some 'group10' data
);


# Break input string into:  group N - N   (and sort by first then second number)

@list = 
    map  { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] or $a->[4] <=> $b->[4] }
    map  { [ $_, /[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+|\-/g ] } 
    @list;

say for @list;
```

The regex extracts both numbers and words from the string, for sorting. But if that lone substring is always indeed the same (`group`) then we only ever sort by numbers and can use `/[0-9]+/g`, and compare numerically arrayref elements at indices `1` and `2`.

Prints

```
group1-1
group1-2
group1-9
group1-10
group2-1
group2-2
group2-9
group2-10
group10-1
group10-2
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd make sure the strings in the list follows the pattern (`\S+\d+-\d+`) and then use `cmp` for the string comparison part and `<=>` for the numbers:

```
sub compare {
    if( $a =~ /(\S+)(\d+)-(\d+)/ ) {
        my($A1,$A2,$A3) = ($1,$2,$3);
        if( $b =~ /(\S+)(\d+)-(\d+)/ ) {
            my($B1,$B2,$B3) = ($1,$2,$3);
            return ($A1 cmp $B1) || ($A2 <=> $B2) || $A3 <=> $B3;
        }
    }
    $a cmp $b; # fallback if a string doesn't follow the pattern
};
```

Comment: You can use `return ($A1 cmp $B1) || ($A2 <=> $B2) || ($A3 <=> $B3)` for the inner thing instead of the `if`s. `||` will short-circuit on -1 or 1 and fall through on 0. It's a common idiom.

Answer (score 2):

##### Natural sort

What you want is called a "natural sort".

```perl
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

my @sorted = natsort @unsorted;
```

It can also be performed in-place.

```perl
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort_inplace );

natsort_inplace @array;
```

##### Key sort

For when you want more control.

```perl
use Sort::Key::Multi qw( uukeysort );

my @sorted = uukeysort { /(\d+)/g } @unsorted;
```

or

```perl
use Sort::Key::Multi qw( uukeysort_inplace );

uukeysort_inplace { /(\d+)/g } @array;
```

##### Without modules (Unoptimized)

```perl
my @sorted =
   sort {
      my ($ag, $an) = $a =~ /(\d+)/g;
      my ($bg, $bn) = $b =~ /(\d+)/g;
      $ag <=> $bg || $an <=> $bn
   }
      @unsorted;
```

##### Without modules (Schwartzian transform)

This avoids repeating the same work. Instead of extracting the info 2*N*log2(N) times, it only extracts it N times.

```perl
my @sorted =
   map $_->[0],
      sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }
         map [ $_, /(\d+)/g ],
            @unsorted;
```

##### Without modules (GRT)

An optimization of ST.

```perl
my @sorted =
   map substr($_->[0], 8),
      sort
         map pack('NNa*', /(\d+)/g, $_),
            @unsorted;
```